# how to count characters in a string and how to count odd numbers JS

Tags: javascript

i am on my first week of learning javascript; i am a bit confused on how to approach these questions. Please note that you are NOT supposed to console log; the code should run exactly as written to check.

Write a function called **countCharacters** that takes one argument called **word**, which is a string. When **countCharacters** is invoked it will return the number of characters is in the word

```js
countCharacters('hello') // => should return 5
countCharacters('cookie monster') // => should return 14
countCharacters('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') // => should return 26
```

For this question i am stuck on how to write a function that will count the characters in a string..

```js
function odd(myArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray.length[i] % 2 === 1) {
      return myArray);
    }
  }
}
```

Write a function called **odd** that takes one argument called **myArray**, which is an array of numbers. When **odd** is invoked it will log to the console all numbers in the array that are odd

```js
odd([1, 4, 6, 7, 3]) // => should log 1, 7, & 3;
odd([3, 4, 1, 7, 13]) // => should log 3, 1, 7, & 13
```

or this question i have tried

```js
function odd(myArray) {
  for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray.length[i] % 2 === 1) {
      return myArray);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your initial question got answered. Don't remove the old question and fill it with a new one. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I reverted the question to the original one. If you make such an action again, the question will be flagged and probably closed.

Answer (score 4):

[String](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) has a [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property. It represents the length of a String.

```js
function countCharacters(input) {
  console.log(input.length)
}

countCharacters('hello')
countCharacters('cookie monster')
countCharacters('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Use this function to filter elements from your Array.

```js
function odd(input) {
  console.log(input.filter(v => v % 2))
}

odd([1, 4, 6, 7, 3])
odd([3, 4, 1, 7, 13])
```

**Pro tip**
If you want your function to `return` instead of `logging` then just write `return foo` instead of `console.log(foo)` inside your function body.

**Recommendation**
I also recommend you highly to make some guided course if you want to get into JavaScript without any developing experience. There are many resources out there. One of many to start: [Exercism](https://exercism.org/)

Comment: Check the updated answer. I accidentally clicked "add answer" without the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For counting characters you probably want something other than `return someword.length` so here is an alternative.

```js
function countCharacters ( aWord ){
   let counter  = 0 ;

   for(const aChar of aWord ) {
      counter ++ ; // exactly like (counter = counter + 1 )
   }

   return  counter ;
}

//test results

let myName = 'mynamehas16chars'
console.log('myName contains',countCharacters(myName),'chars');
```

This code simply increments counter for each character in `aWord` to count them .

Comment: Cool function. What is the difference between your solution and String.length? Is there any reason to re-implement a type property like String.length as custom function? IMO it creates new functionality that is already supported by the language itself. Therefore you have one more potential source of error.

Comment: Of course , `.length` is a cached value of this function so that we dont count array every time we want to  know it's length . I only made this code to help beginners know another way of doing things , and expand the possibilities.